# fadeIn on page load

Tags: jquery, css

I want to fade in a background of an entry within a div - this is to show the user what the most recent entry is on page load.

I want it to do it on page load, without having to click or hover or anything, just when the page loads.

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#box').fadeIn(5000, function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

Is it something like pageLoad?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: pageLoad is like document ready, is that not working?

Comment: @kerry there is a difference between pageLoad and document.ready specially when he is asking about images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the **[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)** event which fires page loads:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#box').fadeIn(5000, function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `$(document).ready(...)` and `$(window).load(...)`? I'm still new enough to jQuery, and haven't come across the latter alternative before. =)

Comment: @ricebowl: `ready` handler runs when DOM (document object model) becomes ready (faster/earlier) while `load` runs when all resources of pages including DOM, images, frames, etc have loaded (slower) but important when it comes to images/frames.

Answer (score 1):

not 100% sure but have you tried

```
window.onload =function() { 
  $('#box').fadeIn(5000, function() { 
    // Animation complete 
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brad, your code should work if you hide the content first and then fade it back in. jQuery cannot fade something that is already showing in the same sense that you cannot fade-out something that is already hidden.

[See example](http://jsbin.com/eloko4)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#box').hide().fadeIn(5000, function() {
    // Animation complete
  });
});
```